# Secret of indexing tons of pages with similar content on Google

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-ranking, seo-audit

I have found few websites that are built using wordpress. All the websites are informational websites providing simple search term queries. These websites have tons and tons of posts all with the similar content just few words here and there. Can anyone please explain me how Google is indexing their posts with similar content.

One of the website from my list:

Opposite-of.com

This site has all the posts with similar content with just few words replaced. The site has nearly 10k+ pages indexed.

Anyone with the knowledge or has built similar site like this can help me out.

Comment: I don't believe there's any secret for thin content. The website you noticed probably just does better in plain vanilla metrics - e.g. quality backlinks and site age. For general tips, see [What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-improve-a-sites-position-in-google)